# Error in named query while deploying jbpm applicaton

Tags: jbpm

I am kind of new to JBPM and trying to deploy a web application that I found as part of a tutorial, on JBoss EAP 7. I am running into an error:

> Error in named query: TasksAssignedAsPotentialOwnerByGroup:
>   org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: name of:
>   org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.TaskImpl [select distinct new
>   org.jbpm.services.task.query.TaskSummaryImpl( t.id, t.name, t.subject,
>   t.description, t.taskData.status, t.priority,
>   t.taskData.actualOwner.id, t.taskData.createdBy.id,
>   t.taskData.createdOn, t.taskData.activationTime,
>   t.taskData.expirationTime, t.taskData.processId,
>   t.taskData.processInstanceId, t.taskData.parentId,
>   t.taskData.deploymentId, t.taskData.skipable ) from
>   org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.TaskImpl t join
>   t.peopleAssignments.potentialOwners potentialOwners where t.archived =
>   0 and t.taskData.actualOwner = null and t.taskData.status in
>   ('Created', 'Ready', 'Reserved', 'InProgress', 'Suspended') and
>   potentialOwners.id = :groupId order by t.id DESC]
>           at org.hibernate.QueryException.generateQueryException(QueryException.java:120)
>           at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103)
>           at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:218)
>           at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:76)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:150)
>           at org.hibernate.internal.NamedQueryRepository.checkNamedQueries(NamedQueryRepository.java:155)
>           at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.checkNamedQueries(SessionFactoryImpl.java:796)
>           at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:492)
>           at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:422)
>           at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:880)
>           at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
>           at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:167)
>           at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:125)
>           at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:640)
>           at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:209)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>           at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320) Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property:
>   name of: org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.TaskImpl
>           at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:62)
>           at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:56)
>           at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toType(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1855)
>           at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementType.getPropertyType(FromElementType.java:393)
>           at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElement.getPropertyType(FromElement.java:504)
>           at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.getDataType(DotNode.java:660)
>           at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.prepareLhs(DotNode.java:264)
>           at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.resolve(DotNode.java:204)
>           at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:109)
>           at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:104)
>           at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.resolveSelectExpression(DotNode.java:722)
>           at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.resolveSelectExpression(HqlSqlWalker.java:1045)
>           at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2291)
>           at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.constructor(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2649)
>           at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2358)
>           at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExprList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2228)
>           at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1499)
>           at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:583)
>           at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:311)
>           at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:259)
>           at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:262)
>           at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:190)
>           ... 18 more

I verified that TaskImpl class is defined in persistence.xml. And these named queries are defined in Taskorm.xml.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue and posting here for benefit of others. TaskImpl class has changed between jbpm 6 and 7. I was using v7 Taskorm.xml against v6 jar files